# How to install Chutzpah Test Adapter for the Test Explorer - version 3.2.6 in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, chutzpah, visual-studio-gallery

I tried searching all over the internet, but I couldn't find how to install **Chutzpah Test Adapter for the Test Explorer** version **3.2.6** for visual studio 2013. In Visual studio Extensions and Updates settings, I am able to see the latest version (4.0.1).

Any idea where I can get Chutzpah test Adapter 3.2.6 version?

Comment: Thank you for participating at StackOverflow. Could you please include the steps that you have tried so far? For more help on asking good questions, see stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to install it from Visual Studio Tools->Extensions and Updates. After searching in the Gallery, I am able to find only 4.0.1 version

Answer (score 0):

You can find an older version of the VSIX here (https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/releases/tag/v3.3.1). This is version 3.3.1 which hopefully is good enough.